# What is SRU in solaris? How to find the SRU number?

Tags: solaris

I used `pkg list entire` command , and i got the output for `version column` as follows :
`0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.24.2`.
How to find the SRU from this?
Can we upgrade/ downgrade to a particular SRU ?

Answer (score 4):

SRU is an abbreviation for *Support Repository Update*, installing new package versions from the support repo for that OS, much like installing a patch cluster for older Solaris releases.

The various fields in the version is explained in [Oracle Solaris Package Versioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36856/pkgos.html#PKDEVglyvm).

Oracle only makes SRUs available to customers with support contracts - if you have a support contract you can read more about SRU's in the Oracle Support Knowledgebase at [Solaris 11 Support Repositories Explained](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1021281.1), and see what fixes are available in each SRU for [Solaris 11.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1501435.1) and [Solaris 11.2](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1672221.1).

Answer (score 2):

If you run 'pkg info entire' it will show the SRU name in human readable format also (if you have installed from the support repo - otherwise it shows the Release info). The 4th digit in 0.175.1.0.0.24.2 is the SRU number

In the example above it is the base Solaris 11.1 release - no SRU has been installed yet.
If an SRU had been installed on top of that you'd get a version like 0.5.11-0.175.1.21.4.1 (aka Oracle Solaris 11.1 SRU21.4.1)

You can easily upgrade to an SRU but you can't downgrade unless you have an older Boot Environment (BE) from which to upgrade to the SRU you want.