# How to check version of libpkcs11 on Solaris

Tags: solaris, pkcs#11, sunos

As stated in subject. How to check in terminal which version of `pkcs11` I've got on SunOS 5.11?

How is it possible to update this library? It is causing me some issues to my Java standalone application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libpkcs11 library is part of the Solaris 11 system/library package. You query the package and its version with this command:

```
$ pkg search -l /usr/lib/libpkcs11.so
INDEX      ACTION VALUE                PACKAGE
path       link   usr/lib/libpkcs11.so pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.2
```

Should you want to update it, you need to update Solaris 11 itself to a newer version (eg: 11.2 or a newer [SRU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951486/what-is-sru-in-solaris-how-to-find-the-sru-number))